# ¿Cómo reemplazar parte del texto en un párrafo con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy recibiendo un texto de una api el cual queda en una etiqueta `<p>` sin embargo, se quiere que desde un length especifico se reemplace por `...` esto normalmente se podría hacer con css con `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis` sin embargo el texto es pequeño, se quiere que en la segunda línea se corte por los `...` por lo que esto no me serviria, tengo pensado con JavaScript leer el tamaño del texto con mitexto.length desde la posición 15 en adelante sustituirlo por los `...` pero ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Comment: Quieres que haga como en los periódicos en las noticias de pago?

Comment: Mmm, no estoy seguro a que se refiere exactamente, pero si, cortar el texto en un length especifico u sustituir por los ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes recortar tu texto usando [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
let texto = "Texto con mas de 15 caracteres para recortar y mostrar despues tres puntos";
let p = document.getElementById('txt');
p.innerText = texto.slice(0,15) + "...";
```

```html
<p id="txt"></p>
```

Con el slice del ejemplo le decimos *Coge del string desde el caracter 0 hasta el 15* y después le concatenamos los 3 puntos.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono